# Linked List Pointers Javascript, append method

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

i think this code works well with creating a linked list and appending to it,
but i do not understand the little piece of code below which i commented it please help.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = new Node(value);
    this.tail = this.head;
    this.length = 1;
  }
  append(value) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    // how come that we did not even mention this.head and it keeps adding to it??
    this.tail.next = newNode; //<<<<< can not figure this one
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.length++;

    return this;
  }
}

//test code
let myLinkedList = new LinkedList(10);

myLinkedList.append(5);
myLinkedList.append(16);
myLinkedList.append(14);
console.log(myLinkedList);
```

what i tried to understand >>>

```
    // instantiation
p = { a: 1, b: null };
c = p;

// what happens when i call append
node = { a: 2, b: null };
c.b = node;
console.log(p);
c = node;

node1 = { a: 3, b: null };
c.b = node1;
console.log(p);
c = node1;

node2 = { a: 4, b: null };
c.b = node2;
console.log(p);
c = node2;
```

i wanna know how `c` access exactly the last `b` property in `p` object,
does every b has it's own memory address or because `c` contains `a: 4` with it so when i say `c.b` it access the `b` that has `a: 4` with it?

Comment: Because in the constructor there is this statement `this.tail = this.head;`

Comment: yes i thought about it but still do not understand, can you explain more

Comment: i mean when we change this.tail.next it changes this.head but,
 when we change this.tail this.head do not respond? how ?

Comment: When a new instance of `LinkedList` is created, `this.tail` is a reference to `this.head` (both variables point to the same `Node`), then, each time `append` is called, `this.tail` is changed to point to the latest created `Node`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, rely appreciate it, i added a part that can better demonstrate my confusion can you check it please!

Comment: Every `c = node`, `c = node1`, etc. statement resets `c` so it doesn't have any relationship with `p` anymore. Think of `c` as an address, a way to find a specific place in memory. Every assignment statement `c = ...` changes the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies within the memory management methodology of how JavaScript works,

let me show you an example, lets say we have a class,

```
class Wait{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name
        this.next = null
    }
}
```

Now here is what we are expected to do with Append method in LinkedLists

Example 1>

```
let wait = new Wait('john')
let wait1 = new Wait('doe')
let wait2 = new Wait('foo')
let wait3 = new Wait('bar')
wait.next = wait1
wait1.next = wait2
wait2.next = wait3
console.log(JSON.stringify(wait))
```

// Output:

```
{"name":"john","next":{"name":"doe","next":{"name":"foo","next":{"name":"bar","next":null}}}}
```

here `wait`, `wait1`, `wait2` and `wait3` are Javascript reference objects, so each of them are store in stack memory separately but they also point to one another due to assignment (`=`).

so for an instance `wait2` is a reference object in itself in the stack, but as soon as you do `wait1.next = wait2`, the later is now pointing to the former object.

so you essentially form a chain of reference objects, you are not modifying any Object address, you are just connecting their pointers.

An interesting observation would be that, even though you are not changing anything in `wait`, its value keeps changing with every `next`, that is because reference objects in JavaScripts are basically pointers in stack memory, and here as we keep adding pointers to its subsequent references, the value of `wait` keeps changing.

with that being said let me come to, how it works in LinkedList class,

Considering the above scenario,

Example 2>

```
 class VaccinationLine{
    constructor(){
        this.watingList = null 
        this.reference = null 
    }
    add(name){  
        let member = new Wait(name)
        if(this.watingList == null){
            this.watingList = member
            this.reference = member
        }else{
            this.reference.next = member
            this.reference = member //or = this.reference.next, both are same
            
        }
        return this.watingList
    }
}

let waitlist = new VaccinationLine()
waitlist.add('john')
waitlist.add('doe')
waitlist.add('foo')
waitlist.add('bar')
console.log(JSON.stringify(waitlist))
```

//Output

```
{"watingList":{"name":"john","next":{"name":"doe","next":{"name":"foo","next":{"name":"bar","next":null}}}},"reference":{"name":"bar","next":null}}
```

In the above code, when you do `let member = new Wait(name)`, it creates a reference object in stack memory and stores the contents in heap.

Now initially both of them are pointing to the same `member` object, but as we proceed further in loop, we only change the `this.reference`, the same way we did in our first example where we were creating a chain of `wait1`,`wait2` etc. and as shown in code output for example 1, (i.e. as we add to the chain of objects the value of `wait` also keeps changing).

In similar manner because `this.waitingList` is our first object reference in line, as we keep adding objects to `next` property of subsequent `this.reference` objects in chain, the value of `this.waitingList` keeps changing.